# A user has 2 active bounties

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

From the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty):

> There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time.

Somehow [one user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/12549/myqlarson?tab=bounties) has 2 active bounties right now: both on [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/why-does-american-english-pluralize-certain-singular-nouns) and on [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40572/is-it-true-that-a-word-ending-in-y-is-more-likely-to-be-an-adjective-than-a-noun).  Perhaps it has to do with the fact that one bounty is on a question asked by that user, and another is on one asked by someone else.

How is this possible?

Comment: The user now has 3.

Comment: The user now has 24 rep.

Comment: I don't get it. Does [this user](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) randomly assign bounties? Why?

Comment: No. Myqlarson (no longer a user) assigned them.  (He seemed determined to keep himself under 100 rep.)  His account must have been deleted, since I can't find him by searching all users. I suppose Community automatically receives responsibility for all unowned bounties, as well as CW posts and downvotes on deleted posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813),

> We now allow for up to 3 concurrent bounties per user.
>
> We will be analyzing the effect over the next few weeks.

The FAQ will have to be corrected by a dev.

Comment: sorry about that -- putting the faq update on my `todo.txt`

Comment: So if I had just waited for a day or two, I would have been answered by the FAQ?